# cycle with chemfig

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I am trying to draw cyclobutane with chemfig

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{H_2C?[a]-CH_2-[:-90]CH_2-[:180]H_2C?[a]-}
\end{document}
```

How do I get rid of the "little piece of bound" overlapping the carbone at the bottom right corner ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the last hyphen:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{H_2C?[a]-CH_2-[:-90]CH_2-[:180]H_2C?[a]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use *4() to make a square ring

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{*4(H_2C?-CH_2-CH_2-H_2C?)}
\end{document}
```

[image]